# Adding HttpHandler to SharePoint 2010 to rename PDFs on download

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have been looking around for awhile now and I can't seem to find an up to date example and my current knowledge of SharePoint as a whole is fairly minimal. What I need to do is append a column from a document library as well as the last date modified to PDFs as they are downloaded. As far as I can see there isn't a built in way to do this with SharePoint and the way to go is to produce an HttpHandler that changes the file name before it is downloaded.

[Link](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2012/03/stamping-pdf-files-downloaded-from-sharepoint-2010/)

I found this which is a good start and adding the code to manipulate the file name seems straightforward, but where I get stuck is actually creating the proper files and deploying it to SharePoint.

Any suggestions or examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure where you are facing the issue. The article specifies how to create the feature which would add the HttpHandler and the required web config changes.

Comment: The issue derives from not knowing how to properly deploy the solution to SharePoint. That and a lot of examples say you need to use an ASP.NET handler (.ashx). What I really need is a crash course on SharePoint dev I suppose.

Comment: Copy the Feature folder to the server and use the STSDAM tool to deploy the solution

Comment: This is my process right now: create a blank project, add a class and add code to manipulate file name, add feature, add feature event receiver, add code to activate and deactivate the HttpHandler. Then I build this and deploy it? Sorry for the required hand holding, just trying to wrap my head around SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to packade your VisualStudio SharePoint project (features, packages etc.) in to a **.wsp** file. A **.wsp** file is simply a zip file that contains your artifacts that are going to be deployed to the hive (14 folder).

I would recommend you to use CKS Dev where you can in an easy way create the wsp.
It is an open source plugin to VS 2010 found on code plex.
[CKS Dev on CodePlex](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/)

Next step is to copy this wsp to the server where it needs to be installed. And then issue some powershell commands on the server to install your code.
[Here is a link taking you through the steps of deployment](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-deploy-a-wsp-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/)

So in short:
1. Create wsp
2. Copy wsp
3. Install wsp on server

I hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to be able to help.